# touch element using selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, webbot

I have some problem with selenium (chromeDriver).

There is a webpage which is designed for mobile, that page have two inputs. When you click on each of them an embedded keyboard(or virtual keyboard) will pop up and end user can use the keyboard buttons for putting text into inputs, but as I said page designed for mobile so you can not click on keyboard, it just works on mobile, that means if you change Chrome mode (to mobile mode) then you can click on keyboard buttons(virtual keyboard on web page)!

I need some things(some driver/trick ) to click on keyboard numbers without problem or just emulate phone mode. I  know selenium has phone mode, but it just change dimensions(is not a real phone mode).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for appium.

> Appium is an open source test automation framework for use with
> native, hybrid and mobile web apps.

and

> It drives iOS, Android, and Windows apps using the WebDriver protocol.

here is the the [official documentation](https://appium.io/docs/en/about-appium/intro/)

for installation, refer [here](https://appium.io/docs/en/about-appium/getting-started/?lang=en)

Comment: tanks for your advice . and yes i think appium will solve my problem , but i solved the problem using jquery trigger , something like below code :
var excutor = (IJavascriptExcutor)driver ;
excutor.excute("$(.myclass).trigger('touchend')")  ;